# Get class definition from type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a situation where I'd like to be able to pass a Type as a generic parameter.  My problem is that once I use typeof() to obtain a Type, I cannot figure out how to get this back into a form that would allow me to pass it as a generic parameter, *even though the type is still a class type*.

The below is purely to demonstrate my issue, I'm not actually calling typeof() on something that's already constrained as a class type:

```
public void Example<T>() where T : class
{
  //This works fine.
  var firstList = new List<T>();

  Type aType = typeof(T);

  //This resolves to true.
  bool thisIsTrue = aType.IsClass;

  //This does not compile?!?
  var secondList = new List<aType>();
}
```

Answering any of the following questions would likely solve my issue:

-- Is there a command similar to typeof(), .GetType(), etc., that would allow me to constrain the result to a class, so the compiler would accept it for a generic parameter?  Then I could avoid the issue of going from type to class altogether.

-- Is there actually a way to transform a type into a class?  I couldn't find a way to do it from either the type or an instantiated object of said type.

-- As a last resort, am I going to need to dynamically define these classes at runtime to actually get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.100).aspx) method

```
var secondListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(aType);
var secondList = (List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(secondListType);
```

Comment: Cool! I never knew about the typeof(List<>) syntax. I was going to bring up the `MakeGenericType` method, but that makes life a bit easier.

Comment: If you use MakeGeneric type, you should be able to safely cast secondList as IList (not IList<>) to make it easier to work with.